# How to draw custom shape in flutter and drag that shape around?

Tags: flutter, dart

At the moment I can draw rectangles using CustomPainter. Below the code inside the paint method of my CustomPainter.

```
for (var rectPoints in rectangles) {
  paint.color = rectPoints.color;
  paint.strokeWidth = rectPoints.strokeWidth;
  if (rectPoints.selected != null && rectPoints.selected == true) {
    paint.color = Colors.black45;
  }
  var rect = Rect.fromLTWH(
      rectPoints.startPoint.dx,
      rectPoints.startPoint.dy,
      rectPoints.endPoint.dx - rectPoints.startPoint.dx,
      rectPoints.endPoint.dy - rectPoints.startPoint.dy);
  canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
}

var rect = Rect.fromLTWH(startPoint.dx, startPoint.dy,
    endPoint.dx - startPoint.dx, endPoint.dy - startPoint.dy);
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```

A rectangle is a custom object with startPoint, endPoint and some other properties needed to draw that specific rectangle. Now I want to select a rectangle and re-position it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61470963/6665568

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to track the state of the rectangles' positions independent of the canvas drawing. The easiest way to do that is to use a StatefulWidget. You'll also need to use a GestureDetector to capture the pan events. Then you can wire up the gesture details to the position of the rectangles and call the painter to redraw everything.

Here's a simple app that shows how to do it with one rectangle. Should be straightforward to expand it to handle multiple ones.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Draggable Custom Painter',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomPainterDraggable(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomPainterDraggable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomPainterDraggableState createState() => _CustomPainterDraggableState();
}

class _CustomPainterDraggableState extends State<CustomPainterDraggable> {
  var xPos = 0.0;
  var yPos = 0.0;
  final width = 100.0;
  final height = 100.0;
  bool _dragging = false;

  /// Is the point (x, y) inside the rect?
  bool _insideRect(double x, double y) =>
      x >= xPos && x <= xPos + width && y >= yPos && y <= yPos + height;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: (details) => _dragging = _insideRect(
        details.globalPosition.dx,
        details.globalPosition.dy,
      ),
      onPanEnd: (details) {
        _dragging = false;
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        if (_dragging) {
          setState(() {
            xPos += details.delta.dx;
            yPos += details.delta.dy;
          });
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: RectanglePainter(Rect.fromLTWH(xPos, yPos, width, height)),
          child: Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  RectanglePainter(this.rect);
  final Rect rect;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(rect, Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have developed a library called
[touchable](https://pub.dev/packages/touchable) for the purpose of adding gesture callbacks to each individual shape you draw on the canvas. You can draw your shapes and add `onPanUpdate` or `onTapDown` callbacks to drag your shape around.

Here's what you can do to detect touch and drag on your circle.

Here's a small example taken directly from the pub dev site :

Wrap your CustomPaint widget with CanvasTouchDetector. It takes a builder function as argument that expects your CustomPaint widget as shown below.

```dart
import 'package:touchable/touchable.dart';


CanvasTouchDetector(
    builder: (context) => 
        CustomPaint(
            painter: MyPainter(context)
        )
)
```

Inside your CustomPainter class's paint method , create and use the TouchyCanvas object (using the context obtained from the CanvasTouchDetector and canvas) to draw your shape and you can give gesture callbacks like onPanUpdate , onTapDown here to detect your drag events.

```
var myCanvas = TouchyCanvas(context,canvas);
myCanvas.drawRect( rect , Paint() , onPanUpdate: (detail){
    //This callback runs when you drag this rectangle. Details of the location can be got from the detail object.
    //Do stuff here. Probably change your state and animate
});
```

Comment: Thx! Will evaluate.